# How to seek to new location while paused with androids MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm using `MediaPlayer` class to play video in my android app. How can I pause the video, jump to another location, and while video still paused show frame from this new location. Currently I do something like `mp.pause(); mp.seekTo(); mp.start(); mp.Pause();` but this more often then not doesn't update the frame.

I also tried to update via onSeekComplete() but couldn't get it working. It seems like pretty easy problem to fix yet I can't get it working. How is it done in popular video players? What is the common way to do it?